# Get public key from CSR or CRT

Tags: certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have certificate request that contains RSA Public-Key. Looks like Modulus part is public key by itself. But according to my understanding it must contain 256 bytes while modulus part contains 257 ones. Should I omit first 00 byte?

Why public key is located in Modulus and what is Exponent?

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = San Fransisco, O = MLopsHub, OU = MlopsHub Dev, CN = www.aaa.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:bd:57:66:25:c2:b1:15:05:3f:84:ee:c4:f7:38:
                    81:21:b1:ea:45:17:93:88:ec:f2:47:14:3a:fe:c5:
                    37:33:a9:03:35:5a:28:a1:de:f8:27:31:b3:01:cb:
                    16:ef:d8:0b:7a:4e:da:66:11:e1:47:4d:49:85:1d:
                    06:d1:66:48:34:aa:7b:a2:7c:34:d9:13:d1:91:95:
                    15:e7:d4:b1:d4:7c:ce:65:21:1c:78:6e:dd:3e:ba:
                    71:4e:f7:6a:93:d0:6c:3b:8c:05:98:e6:12:b6:c1:
                    e7:b6:1a:f3:dd:db:89:12:ba:6e:f7:28:0a:d9:a8:
                    1b:1f:21:17:2d:25:80:20:6a:dd:7c:9f:0b:25:a6:
                    2a:a0:ac:d9:19:85:75:65:93:93:9c:c0:e8:ec:db:
                    94:fd:37:ca:f3:66:5f:c0:0c:a2:24:eb:6d:e3:a6:
                    24:89:56:10:89:95:e0:cf:e8:27:fd:df:2b:4b:ce:
                    1d:43:38:2b:4f:ed:63:96:18:ef:69:e2:f5:84:39:
                    70:10:38:42:c6:a5:a0:ad:1c:be:06:ca:bb:f4:50:
                    21:22:38:b5:7c:6a:d3:58:9b:a3:44:ed:7d:39:52:
                    9d:c4:77:fc:5f:59:a1:b4:9e:f1:93:88:74:01:44:
                    f3:b4:40:b3:03:32:93:27:dd:54:c0:fd:bb:6d:91:
                    fc:c3
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
            a0:00
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         56:42:65:6b:78:24:3e:3d:f1:01:c5:7e:a1:bd:ef:f9:79:3c:
         dc:e1:66:24:75:43:4b:d5:86:77:d8:0c:cd:57:a2:89:13:fe:
         96:e8:f2:a2:ae:81:6d:99:82:28:1b:4d:70:c7:e8:f5:1f:8d:
         16:86:4b:87:d9:f3:61:0e:d7:e1:34:89:f3:ba:fc:28:6b:94:
         55:89:8a:46:33:2e:51:c3:05:bf:35:c7:06:61:5e:ab:9a:45:
         7c:ae:07:61:8d:85:8c:9d:ec:0c:6c:60:17:53:f7:ce:f1:e8:
         30:c5:ee:7e:f9:ed:a0:ae:44:44:0e:6c:47:26:89:7e:93:0a:
         c9:ec:45:ec:38:a0:1f:9e:a7:3e:63:0b:d7:a0:ec:b5:1a:ee:
         07:6f:9f:29:e7:f4:70:ef:1d:98:3d:5c:61:6b:4a:19:de:b7:
         bf:0f:98:4f:62:25:85:19:73:1d:02:ab:a0:e7:a7:6e:d8:b0:
         79:90:a0:bd:41:8e:68:d3:71:4d:6e:60:52:16:7e:37:91:b1:
         19:8b:26:f9:33:df:38:b5:a8:51:8d:40:ee:82:04:e8:dd:23:
         9a:72:1e:4d:cc:db:b1:31:e0:6f:40:00:03:9c:af:da:62:5b:
         85:d9:82:7e:3a:6f:a5:9f:37:0c:24:b1:cb:c8:36:b0:b5:2c:
         37:2f:8c:9e
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why public key is located in Modulus and what is Exponent?

It is *literally* a modulus. Take a look at the [RSA encryption process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption) – it involves a mathematical formula where *n* is the "Modulus" value and *e* is the "Exponent".

Unlike (most) symmetric ciphers whose keys are just bit strings, common asymmetric ciphers often use actual numeric values as part of some mathematical expression. So you shouldn't be looking exclusively for large hexdumps that "look like keys" – the same modulus value could just as well have been written in decimal, like the exponent was.

Note that in most cases, you will need to both the modulus *and* the exponent as your "public key" (unless it was previously agreed that a standard exponent such as 65537 will always be used). In PKI certificates, the entire "Subject Public Key Info" structure – not just the Modulus field – is the public key.

> But according to my understanding it must contain 256 bytes while modulus part contains 257 ones. Should I omit first 00 byte?

In X.509 certificates, the modulus is stored as an 'INTEGER' ASN.1 type (because it is in fact an integer, not just a series of bytes). This data type holds a signed integer of any length.

As the value is stored as a *signed* integer, the highest bit of the first byte indicates whether the number is positive or negative. But the modulus in your example (0xbd57...) already happens to have its highest bit set, so according to ASN.1 DER format rules it must be stored prefixed with a 0x00 byte to make sure it wouldn't be misinterpreted as a negative number.

Because it's still a number, the extra 0x00 prefix doesn't change the meaning of the value (just like "000123" is still the decimal number as "123"). Whether you *can* omit it or not depends on how you're using the value. For example, when specifying it as an integer literal (`modulus = 0xbd5766..`) it can be omitted because negative values would be indicated by a minus sign – but keeping it won't hurt either. But if you're running the value through some kind of "byte[] to bigint" function, it might require the prefix to be kept.